# How to create a form by java swing

Tags: java, swing

I don't know whether it's called *form*, so i will try to describe it by listing its features.
Here is an example:
[image: example pictrue]

or you can see the pic [here](https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/wiki/Artoria_Pendragon).

1. It is composed of key(e.g Rank or Hits) and value(e.g A or 1).
2. Its looks like JTable, but its key and value may be in any cell and don't have a TableHeader, I don't know how to achieve it by JTable.
3. Its cells' width is not same and fixed.
4. Text in every cell can be selected and copy.

I have tried to put JLabel(set inset 0, use MatteBorder and gridbaglayout) together to achieve the 'form', it works but inconvenient. For example, put two labels (inset is 0 and has LineBorder) together, the borders where they intersect do not coincide, but instead look like 2px borders. So, I have to use MatteBorder(left and top border is 1px, right border will be 1px when the cell is in last column).

I would like to know what this kind of information table is called, how to achieve it conveniently or what keywords should I search.

Update:
I already know that it has to be customized by myself, I also mentioned a method I tried (use JLabel with no insets and GridBagLayout) above, but the JLabels' border junction looks like a 2-pixel border ([e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2onZK.png)), which makes me have to repeatedly set the four borders of each Label by MatteBorder to avoid the stacking of border lines. Code looks like this:

```java
JLabel attributeLabel = new JLabel("Earth");
attributeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
JLabel genderLabel = new JLabel("Female");
genderLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
```

Then the border could look [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqL04.png).
Is there any good way to solve the border problem and avoid set every label's border.

Comment: *I would like to know what this kind of information table is called* - there is no single component that does exactly that. You can build your own using multiple components on a JPanel with a GridBagLayout.

Comment: Take a look at different layouts within `Swing`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html - I, personally, like the GridBagLayout most (gives you most freedom to arrange elements).

Comment: It's just a table.

Comment: “Text in every cell can be selected and copy.” Does that include the non-data label cells, like **Overcharge Effect**?

Comment: @VGR That's all ok.  it's not a necessary feature compared with other three points, you can think of it as an expansion feature.

Comment: “Is there any good way to solve the border problem and avoid set every label's border.”  As far as I know, the answer is no.  You have to call setBorder on each label.

Answer (score 0):

You can display this in Swing in various ways.

If you use Swing components, align them using a GridLayout or even better GridBagLayout. Make up your mind which Swing components you use - if they are JLabels you will not be able to select and copy the text. In this case you are better off by using JTextField and use setEditable(false).

If you want all text to be selectable in one go - even across cells - you might prefer using a JEditorPane. Switch it into HTML mode and create a suitable HTML document containing a table with all your desired fields. Use the JEditorPane's setText() method to insert the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> It is composed of key(e.g Rank or Hits) and value(e.g A or 1).

I’m going to assume these are the only two keys.  If there are more, it is possible to make the layout more flexible.  If there could be a lot of them, a JTable may be a more appropriate choice.

> Its cells' width is not same and fixed.

GridBagLayout is designed for that exact case.  It’s powerful and flexible, but that creates a potential for complexity, so it is somewhat hard to use properly.

> Text in every cell can be selected and copy.

For now, based on your follow-up comment, I’m going to set aside this requirement, as the text and appearance are easier to accomplish with JLabels, whose text cannot be selected.

First, you’ll want variables to hold all your cells.  Some of them might not need to be kept in private instance fields, if they never change, but I didn’t want to make that assumption.

```
public class SpecSheet {
    private final JLabel baseDamageField;

    private final JLabel rankLabelField;
    private final JLabel rankValueField;

    private final JLabel noblePhantasmTypeLabelField;
    private final JLabel noblePhantasmTypeValueField;

    private final JLabel hitsLabelField;
    private final JLabel hitsValueField;

    private final JLabel perHitPercentageLabelField;
    private final JLabel perHitPercentageValueField;

    private final JLabel effectLabelField;
    private final JLabel effectValueField;

    private final JLabel npLevelLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] npLevelNameFields;

    private final JLabel npLevelDamageLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] npLevelDamageValueFields;

    private final JLabel overchargeEffectLabelField;
    private final JLabel overchargeEffectValueField;

    private final JLabel chargeLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] chargeNameFields;

    private final JLabel chargeNPLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] chargeNPValueFields;

    private final JFrame frame;
```

Then we can define them:

```
public SpecSheet() {
    baseDamageField = new JLabel(" Base Damage: x1.5 ");
    baseDamageField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
        SpecSheet.class.getResource("buster.png")));
    baseDamageField.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    baseDamageField.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

    rankLabelField = new JLabel("Rank");
    rankValueField = new JLabel("A");

    noblePhantasmTypeLabelField = new JLabel("Noble Phantasm Type");
    noblePhantasmTypeValueField = new JLabel("Anti-Fortress");

    hitsLabelField = new JLabel("Hits");
    hitsValueField = new JLabel(" 1 ");

    perHitPercentageLabelField = new JLabel("Per Hit Percentage");
    perHitPercentageValueField = new JLabel("100%");

    effectLabelField = new JLabel("Effect");
    effectValueField = new JLabel("Deals damage to all enemies.");
    effectValueField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
        SpecSheet.class.getResource("increase.png")));
    effectValueField.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEADING);

    npLevelLabelField = new JLabel("NP Level");
    npLevelNameFields = new JLabel[] {
        new JLabel("1"),
        new JLabel("2"),
        new JLabel("3"),
        new JLabel("4"),
        new JLabel("5"),
    };

    npLevelDamageLabelField = new JLabel("Damage+");
    npLevelDamageLabelField.setIcon(
        new ImageIcon(SpecSheet.class.getResource("damage-boost.png")));
    npLevelDamageValueFields = new JLabel[] {
        new JLabel("300%"),
        new JLabel("400%"),
        new JLabel("450%"),
        new JLabel("475%"),
        new JLabel("500%"),
    };

    overchargeEffectLabelField = new JLabel("Overcharge Effect");
    overchargeEffectValueField =
        new JLabel("Charges own NP gauge");

    chargeLabelField = new JLabel("Charge");
    chargeNameFields = new JLabel[] {
        new JLabel("100%"),
        new JLabel("200%"),
        new JLabel("300%"),
        new JLabel("400%"),
        new JLabel("500%"),
    };

    chargeNPLabelField = new JLabel("NP+");
    chargeNPLabelField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
        SpecSheet.class.getResource("np-boost.png")));
    chargeNPValueFields = new JLabel[] {
        new JLabel("20%"),
        new JLabel("27.5%"),
        new JLabel("35%"),
        new JLabel("42.5%"),
        new JLabel("50%"),
    };
```

(Note: `SpecSheet.class.getResource` expects the image file to reside in the *same package* as the SpecSheet class itself.  This is by design;  you don’t want to place images in the root of an application, since that increases the chance they will conflict with something else in the classpath.)

Next, we want to set their appearance.  I found it cleaner to move that task into private methods:

```
updateFonts();
updateColors();
updateBorders();
```

The methods are a bit painstaking, but you only have write them once:

```
private void updateFonts() {
    JLabel[] boldLabelFields = {
        baseDamageField,
        rankLabelField,
        noblePhantasmTypeLabelField,
        hitsLabelField,
        perHitPercentageLabelField,
        effectLabelField,
        npLevelLabelField,
        npLevelDamageLabelField,
        overchargeEffectLabelField,
        chargeLabelField,
        chargeNPLabelField,
    };
    JLabel[][] boldFieldSets = {
        boldLabelFields,
        npLevelNameFields,
        chargeNameFields,
    };
    for (JLabel[] fieldSet : boldFieldSets) {
        for (JLabel field : fieldSet) {
            Font font = field.getFont();
            font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
            field.setFont(font);
        }
    }

    JLabel[] plainLabelFields = {
        rankValueField,
        noblePhantasmTypeValueField,
        hitsValueField,
        perHitPercentageValueField,
        overchargeEffectValueField,
    };
    JLabel[][] plainFieldSets = {
        plainLabelFields,
        npLevelDamageValueFields,
        chargeNPValueFields,
    };
    for (JLabel[] fieldSet : plainFieldSets) {
        for (JLabel field : fieldSet) {
            Font font = field.getFont();
            font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
            field.setFont(font);
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the colors:

```
private void updateColors() {
    Color lightPink = Color.decode("#f6dde9");
    Color darkPink = Color.decode("#e5ccd8");

    Color lightGray = Color.decode("#ebebeb");
    Color darkGray = Color.decode("#dfdfdf");

    baseDamageField.setBackground(lightPink);
    overchargeEffectValueField.setBackground(lightPink);
    for (JLabel npField : chargeNPValueFields) {
        npField.setBackground(lightPink);
    }

    overchargeEffectLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);
    chargeLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);
    for (JLabel nameField : chargeNameFields) {
        nameField.setBackground(darkPink);
    }
    chargeNPLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);

    rankLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    noblePhantasmTypeLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    hitsLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    perHitPercentageLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    effectLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    npLevelLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    npLevelDamageLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
    for (JLabel nameField : npLevelNameFields) {
        nameField.setBackground(darkGray);
    }

    rankValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    noblePhantasmTypeValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    hitsValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    perHitPercentageValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    effectValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    for (JLabel valueField : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
        valueField.setBackground(lightGray);
    }
}
```

And finally, the part you explicitly asked about—setting the borders:

```
private void updateBorders() {
    Color borderColor = Color.decode("#bfbfbf");

    Border leftOnly =
        BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 0, borderColor);
    rankLabelField.setBorder(leftOnly);
    noblePhantasmTypeLabelField.setBorder(leftOnly);

    Border topOnly =
        BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, borderColor);
    chargeLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    effectLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    npLevelLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    npLevelDamageLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    overchargeEffectLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    chargeLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
    chargeNPLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);

    Border leftAndTop =
        BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, borderColor);
    rankValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    noblePhantasmTypeValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    hitsLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    hitsValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    perHitPercentageLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    perHitPercentageValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    effectValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    npLevelLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    overchargeEffectValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    for (JLabel field : npLevelNameFields) {
        field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    }
    for (JLabel field : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
        field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    }
    for (JLabel field : chargeNameFields) {
        field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    }
    for (JLabel field : chargeNPValueFields) {
        field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
    }
}
```

It’s a pain, but ultimately the method is only 40 lines long.

Going back to our constructor, we’re now ready to assemble everything:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.ipadx = 40;
gbc.ipady = 16;

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridheight = 4;
panel.add(baseDamageField, gbc);

gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridheight = 1;
panel.add(rankLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(rankValueField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(hitsLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(hitsValueField, gbc);

gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridy -= 3;
gbc.gridwidth = 4;
panel.add(noblePhantasmTypeLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(noblePhantasmTypeValueField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(perHitPercentageLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(perHitPercentageValueField, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
panel.add(effectLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panel.add(effectValueField, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
panel.add(npLevelLabelField, gbc);
for (JLabel nameField : npLevelNameFields) {
    gbc.gridx++;
    panel.add(nameField, gbc);
}

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(npLevelDamageLabelField, gbc);
for (JLabel valueField : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
    gbc.gridx++;
    panel.add(valueField, gbc);
}

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(overchargeEffectLabelField, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panel.add(overchargeEffectValueField, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
panel.add(chargeLabelField, gbc);
for (JLabel nameField : chargeNameFields) {
    gbc.gridx++;
    panel.add(nameField, gbc);
}

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
panel.add(chargeNPLabelField, gbc);
for (JLabel valueField : chargeNPValueFields) {
    gbc.gridx++;
    panel.add(valueField, gbc);
}

for (Object child : panel.getComponents()) {
    if (child instanceof JComponent c) {
        // Background colors are only used by opaque Swing components.
        c.setOpaque(true);
    }
    if (child instanceof JLabel label) {
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }
}

frame = new JFrame("Sword of Promised Victory");
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

A complex UI can be tedious to write, but you only have to do it once, so it’s best to just do what you have to do.

Here is the complete program:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SpecSheet {
    private final JLabel baseDamageField;

    private final JLabel rankLabelField;
    private final JLabel rankValueField;

    private final JLabel noblePhantasmTypeLabelField;
    private final JLabel noblePhantasmTypeValueField;

    private final JLabel hitsLabelField;
    private final JLabel hitsValueField;

    private final JLabel perHitPercentageLabelField;
    private final JLabel perHitPercentageValueField;

    private final JLabel effectLabelField;
    private final JLabel effectValueField;

    private final JLabel npLevelLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] npLevelNameFields;

    private final JLabel npLevelDamageLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] npLevelDamageValueFields;

    private final JLabel overchargeEffectLabelField;
    private final JLabel overchargeEffectValueField;

    private final JLabel chargeLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] chargeNameFields;

    private final JLabel chargeNPLabelField;
    private final JLabel[] chargeNPValueFields;

    private final JFrame frame;

    public SpecSheet() {
        baseDamageField = new JLabel(" Base Damage: x1.5 ");
        baseDamageField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            SpecSheet.class.getResource("buster.png")));
        baseDamageField.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        baseDamageField.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

        rankLabelField = new JLabel("Rank");
        rankValueField = new JLabel("A");

        noblePhantasmTypeLabelField = new JLabel("Noble Phantasm Type");
        noblePhantasmTypeValueField = new JLabel("Anti-Fortress");

        hitsLabelField = new JLabel("Hits");
        hitsValueField = new JLabel(" 1 ");

        perHitPercentageLabelField = new JLabel("Per Hit Percentage");
        perHitPercentageValueField = new JLabel("100%");

        effectLabelField = new JLabel("Effect");
        effectValueField = new JLabel("Deals damage to all enemies.");
        effectValueField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            SpecSheet.class.getResource("increase.png")));
        effectValueField.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEADING);

        npLevelLabelField = new JLabel("NP Level");
        npLevelNameFields = new JLabel[] {
            new JLabel("1"),
            new JLabel("2"),
            new JLabel("3"),
            new JLabel("4"),
            new JLabel("5"),
        };

        npLevelDamageLabelField = new JLabel("Damage+");
        npLevelDamageLabelField.setIcon(
            new ImageIcon(SpecSheet.class.getResource("damage-boost.png")));
        npLevelDamageValueFields = new JLabel[] {
            new JLabel("300%"),
            new JLabel("400%"),
            new JLabel("450%"),
            new JLabel("475%"),
            new JLabel("500%"),
        };

        overchargeEffectLabelField = new JLabel("Overcharge Effect");
        overchargeEffectValueField =
            new JLabel("Charges own NP gauge");

        chargeLabelField = new JLabel("Charge");
        chargeNameFields = new JLabel[] {
            new JLabel("100%"),
            new JLabel("200%"),
            new JLabel("300%"),
            new JLabel("400%"),
            new JLabel("500%"),
        };

        chargeNPLabelField = new JLabel("NP+");
        chargeNPLabelField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            SpecSheet.class.getResource("np-boost.png")));
        chargeNPValueFields = new JLabel[] {
            new JLabel("20%"),
            new JLabel("27.5%"),
            new JLabel("35%"),
            new JLabel("42.5%"),
            new JLabel("50%"),
        };

        updateFonts();
        updateColors();
        updateBorders();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.ipadx = 40;
        gbc.ipady = 16;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 4;
        panel.add(baseDamageField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        panel.add(rankLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(rankValueField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(hitsLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(hitsValueField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy -= 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        panel.add(noblePhantasmTypeLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(noblePhantasmTypeValueField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(perHitPercentageLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(perHitPercentageValueField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(effectLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(effectValueField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(npLevelLabelField, gbc);
        for (JLabel nameField : npLevelNameFields) {
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(nameField, gbc);
        }

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(npLevelDamageLabelField, gbc);
        for (JLabel valueField : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(valueField, gbc);
        }

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(overchargeEffectLabelField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(overchargeEffectValueField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(chargeLabelField, gbc);
        for (JLabel nameField : chargeNameFields) {
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(nameField, gbc);
        }

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(chargeNPLabelField, gbc);
        for (JLabel valueField : chargeNPValueFields) {
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(valueField, gbc);
        }

        for (Object child : panel.getComponents()) {
            if (child instanceof JComponent c) {
                // Background colors are only used by opaque Swing components.
                c.setOpaque(true);
            }
            if (child instanceof JLabel label) {
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            }
        }

        frame = new JFrame("Sword of Promised Victory");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private void updateFonts() {
        JLabel[] boldLabelFields = {
            baseDamageField,
            rankLabelField,
            noblePhantasmTypeLabelField,
            hitsLabelField,
            perHitPercentageLabelField,
            effectLabelField,
            npLevelLabelField,
            npLevelDamageLabelField,
            overchargeEffectLabelField,
            chargeLabelField,
            chargeNPLabelField,
        };
        JLabel[][] boldFieldSets = {
            boldLabelFields,
            npLevelNameFields,
            chargeNameFields,
        };
        for (JLabel[] fieldSet : boldFieldSets) {
            for (JLabel field : fieldSet) {
                Font font = field.getFont();
                font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
                field.setFont(font);
            }
        }

        JLabel[] plainLabelFields = {
            rankValueField,
            noblePhantasmTypeValueField,
            hitsValueField,
            perHitPercentageValueField,
            overchargeEffectValueField,
        };
        JLabel[][] plainFieldSets = {
            plainLabelFields,
            npLevelDamageValueFields,
            chargeNPValueFields,
        };
        for (JLabel[] fieldSet : plainFieldSets) {
            for (JLabel field : fieldSet) {
                Font font = field.getFont();
                font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
                field.setFont(font);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateColors() {
        Color lightPink = Color.decode("#f6dde9");
        Color darkPink = Color.decode("#e5ccd8");

        Color lightGray = Color.decode("#ebebeb");
        Color darkGray = Color.decode("#dfdfdf");

        baseDamageField.setBackground(lightPink);
        overchargeEffectValueField.setBackground(lightPink);
        for (JLabel npField : chargeNPValueFields) {
            npField.setBackground(lightPink);
        }

        overchargeEffectLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);
        chargeLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);
        for (JLabel nameField : chargeNameFields) {
            nameField.setBackground(darkPink);
        }
        chargeNPLabelField.setBackground(darkPink);

        rankLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        noblePhantasmTypeLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        hitsLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        perHitPercentageLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        effectLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        npLevelLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        npLevelDamageLabelField.setBackground(darkGray);
        for (JLabel nameField : npLevelNameFields) {
            nameField.setBackground(darkGray);
        }

        rankValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        noblePhantasmTypeValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        hitsValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        perHitPercentageValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        effectValueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        for (JLabel valueField : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
            valueField.setBackground(lightGray);
        }
    }

    private void updateBorders() {
        Color borderColor = Color.decode("#bfbfbf");

        Border leftOnly =
            BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 0, borderColor);
        rankLabelField.setBorder(leftOnly);
        noblePhantasmTypeLabelField.setBorder(leftOnly);

        Border topOnly =
            BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, borderColor);
        chargeLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        effectLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        npLevelLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        npLevelDamageLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        overchargeEffectLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        chargeLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);
        chargeNPLabelField.setBorder(topOnly);

        Border leftAndTop =
            BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, borderColor);
        rankValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        noblePhantasmTypeValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        hitsLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        hitsValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        perHitPercentageLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        perHitPercentageValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        effectValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        npLevelLabelField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        overchargeEffectValueField.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        for (JLabel field : npLevelNameFields) {
            field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        }
        for (JLabel field : npLevelDamageValueFields) {
            field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        }
        for (JLabel field : chargeNameFields) {
            field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        }
        for (JLabel field : chargeNPValueFields) {
            field.setBorder(leftAndTop);
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hide() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException |
                     ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SpecSheet s = new SpecSheet();
            s.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            s.show();
        });
    }
}
```

It is worth mentioning that JavaFX would make some of this noticeably easier.  The colors and fonts could be accomplished with CSS classes.  GridPane has a [setGridLinesVisible](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setGridLinesVisible(boolean)) method which would remove the need for setting borders.